# SQL Query returning unwanted Rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to manipulate some rows returned from a select statement.

At the moment I am getting back multiple rows as the people I am querying, have moved internal accommodation (Houses within the same Site) but I only want to return them, if the Site itself has changed.

For example I am getting..

```
+------------+-------+------------+
| LocationlD | Site  | MovedDate  |
+------------+-------+------------+
|          1 | York  | 01/01/2011 |
|          3 | York  | 02/01/2011 |
|          2 | Leeds | 05/05/2011 |
+------------+-------+------------+
```

In this example, all I would wish to see, if the first York entry, and then the Leeds entry, as the Site has not changed.

Comment: How did you query the database?

Comment: Show us your query, database structure, sample data and expected output. Then we are able to help.

Comment: please read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: stop posting pictures ... post it as text

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT A.LOCATIONLD, A.SITE, A.MOVEDDATE
FROM YOURTABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT SITE, MIN(MOVEDDATE) AS MOVEDDATE_MIN
            FROM YOURTABLE
            GROUP BY SITE) B ON A.SITE = B.SITE AND A.MOVEDDATE = B.MOVEDDATE_MIN;
```

Or in MSSQL from 2005

```
SELECT LOCATIONLD, SITE, MOVEDDATE
FROM (
     SELECT LOCATIONLD, SITE, MOVEDDATE
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITIONED BY SITE ORDER BY MOVEDDATE DESC) AS RN
     FROM YOURTABLE
     ) A
WHERE RN =1;
```

Pls, next time, follow above comments (on how to post a question), specify a database (usually SQL can not be enough) and post what you tried too.